# Laravel multi tanent hyn Package

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am creating a new multi tenant system in laravel 5.2 and wants to use hyn package for this

i am full filling all the requirements which is needed to run a hyn package but when i am installing it using

### composer require hyn/multi-tenant

but i am getting some errors like

```
 Problem 1
- hyn/framework 0.6.1 requires laravel/framework ~5.1.0 -> no matching package found.
- hyn/framework 0.6.0 requires laravel/framework ~5.1.0 -> no matching package found.
- hyn/framework 0.5.0 requires laravel/framework ~5.1.0 -> no matching package found.
- hyn/framework 0.4.1 requires laravel/framework ~5.1.0 -> no matching package found.
- hyn/framework 0.4.0 requires laravel/framework ~5.1.0 -> no matching package found.
- hyn/framework 0.3.0 requires laravel/framework ~5.1.0 -> no matching package found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current codebase of hyn only supports Laravel 5.1 LTS. There's an open issue on Github about this issue.

Reference:
https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant/issues/47

Comment: Thanks for advice so for now hyn package only supports laravel 5.1 i got it

Comment: 5.2 is now supported. you just need to use the `2.x-dev` branch.